# font is not setting bold on router.path even if it is returning true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it is supposed to set bold text on anchor tag but not setting it, not only that it is also removing the first string. can someone please help and explain?

`<a className={'mr-5 hover:text-gray-900 '+ router.pathname == '/' ? 'font-bold':''} WebSite </a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comparison what is happening is: first a concat with the text `mr-5 hover:text-gray-900` with the  `router.pathname` and then comparing with the `/`, which will return always `false`.

In order to fix the issue you need to wrap the ternary in parenthesis:

```
<a className={'mr-5 hover:text-gray-900 '+ (router.pathname == '/' ? 'font-bold' : '')}> WebSite </a>
```